# Как использовать один layout для нескольких Activity

Tags: android, xml

Здравствуйте, я новичок в Android, задался вопросом как можно использовать один xml-файл в нескольких Activity/Fragments.
Есть конкретные объекты, xml-файл отличается парой строк:

object.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/ll_information"
     android:padding="10dp" >

          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:textColor="@color/object_color"
              android:text="@string/object_description" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Хотелось бы использовать этот xml-файл в нескольких `Activity`, за исключением `android:text` и `andoid:textColor`, значение которых будет конкретным для каждого объекта. Как можно обратиться к этим атрибутам и менять их? Спасибо!

Comment: Если у вас одна разметка, вам не нужно несколько активити. Вам нужна одна активити, которая через интент будет принимать параметры  *text* и *color* и программно устанавливать их в разметку. Каждый раз когда вам понадобится активити с нужным текстом и цветом, вы вызываете одну и ту же и интентом ей передаете требуемые параметры.

Comment: спасибо, я это понял. Просто у меня слишком много меняющихся элементов  в каждом xml, примерно 7, то есть стоит ли передавать через `Intent` все эти меняющиеся элементы или лучше использовать разные `layout'ы`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

один xml-файл можно использовать для нескольких Activity/Fragments. Просто в конкретном Activity вставляешь в методе onCreate следующую строку
`setContentView(R.layout.object(или другой xml-файл));`

чтобы записать текст в TextView в коде нужно сначала в xml-файле задать 
`android:id="здесь индентификатор"`

индентификатор - нужен для использования в класе(коде).
Дальше в коде после setContentView находишь view в xml-файле

```
TextView MyText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
```

и передаешь текасту значение

```
MyText.setText("что хочешь?");
```

Где myText - это id который задаем здесь android:id="здесь индентификатор"